# error c2248 friend class inside namespace

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to set up code similar to this:

```
//Class1.h
namespace A {
    class Class1 {
        friend class Class2
        public:
            Class1();
            ~Class1();
        private:
            void Create() { /*do nothing for now*/ };
    };
}

//Class2.h
#include "Class1.h"
namespace A {
    class Class2 {
        void Test();
    };
} //end namespace A

//Class2.cpp
#include "Class2.h"
namespace A {
    void Class2::Test() {
        Class1 object = Class1();
        object.Create(); //error c2248
    }
}
```

And I'm getting the error

> "Error 101 error C2248: 'Class1::Create' : cannot access private
>   member declared in class 'Class1'"

. What would cause this? Am I declaring friendship the wrong way?

Comment: [This works fine](http://ideone.com/nNf6QC) on gcc. Your problem possibly lies somewhere else.

Comment: Also note the missing semicolon in the friend statement.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example with Code:Blocks 13.12 (SDK Version 1.19.0) as well as on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/R7lRo5).

The only **changes I made** to get it compile successfully was

- adding the semicolon after the friend statement
- adding empty blocks `{}` to ctr and dtr of `Class1`
- of course, I also removed the include statements (put all into one file)